# How to make Code Simplified for Variables?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I am having 6 tabs and a object for each . i am recieving data from server and filtering it with tab name .

```
     var a = {} // First Tab Object
    var b = {} // Second Tab Object
    var c = {} // Third Tab Object
    var d = {}// Fourth Tab Object
    var e = {};// Fifth Tab Object
    var f = {};// Sixth Tab Object

this.getService.getData().subscribe( res =>{
    let data = res.filter(data=>{
    return data.oType == this.tabclickedName
    }) 

    if (this.tabclickedName == 'One' ){
    this.a = data
    }
    else if (this.tabclickedName == 'Two' ){
    this.b = data 
    }
    else if (this.tabclickedName == 'Three' ){
    this.c = data 
    }
    else if (this.tabclickedName == 'Four' ){
    this.d = data 
    }
})
```

**1. // Filtering the data from service for clicked tab**

**2. // this.tabclickedName = The tab name which is clicked**

**Problem 1 :- Now i have to write if else statement like this to assign the data for the specified tab**

How to make this code more dynamic so i dont have to write if else statement like this ?

**Problem 2 :- How to avoid using filter in this case and solve the problem using rxjs Operator in service call using pipe or any other rxjs operator ?**

**Approach used : -**

```
let hashTab = {One :'a',two :'b',three:'c',four:'d',five:'e',six:'f'}
let dataTabName = this.hashTab[this.tabclickedName];
```

**Problem In This approach :-**
dataTabName is a string and i want variable insted of that to store data

Comment: where does `oType` property comes from? can you post sample data. also, what does `his.tabClickedName` means?

Comment: Also, reduce your question to a single question.  You're asking two distinct questions, which can make it fall under the category of being "too broad"

Comment: Which in regards to problem one, having an object of `{ 'One': {}, 'Two': {}, 'Three': {}, 'Four': {} }` would let you directly set the content in it with the key of the tabclickedName

Comment: `hashTab[this.tabclickedName] = data;`

Comment: @Taplar hashTab[this.tabclickedName] gives string value

Comment: If you're defaulting it, like you are in your question, and you don't change it, or you change it to a string value, then yeah it would

Comment: @Taplar    if this.clickedName = 'one'     the ouput of              hasTab[this.tabclickedName]  = 'a'   and how can store data int0 this as it will give error so how to correct the code ?

Comment: Please keep in mind changing variable names.  Your code has `this.tabclickedName`, but your last comment has `this.clickedName`.  This can be very confusing.  Assuming you meant to say `this.tabclickedName`, you are defaulting `One` in your example to a string of `a`.  If you never update it, then its value will remain `a`.

Comment: I already did with my third comment.

Comment: @Taplar I cant change the structure of the code as its locked . So is thier anyway we can manipulate this only ?

Comment: What do you mean you can't change the code structure?  If you can't change the code, how are you supposed to change any of this?

Comment: @Taplar var a, var b . var c these variables are used for other purposes also so icant change the code structure i told. i can change the code

Comment: In that case you could use a map, if all the a-f are on the `this` object, you can make a second map of `var hashTab = {One :'a',Two :'b',Three:'c',Four:'d',Five:'e',Six:'f'}`, which would then be used as `this[hashTab[this.tabclickedName]] = data;`.  The hashTab resolves to a-f, which is then used to reference the correct variable on the `this`

Answer (score 1):

You could forego the if-elses by having the variable-names correspond to the tab-names.

Then you could write:

```
this[this.tabclickedName] = data;
```

and be done.

Answer (score 1):

kind of same logic as previous version but with minor corrections
what you could do is put all objects inside an object and rename your children objects

Example:

```
let obj:any = {
    'one': {},
    'two': {},
    'three': {}
}
if(this.tabclickedName != undefined && this.tabclickedName != '')
    this.obj[this.tabclickedName.toLowerCase()] = data
```